# How to use Drupal's flag module to display an Advanced Forum topic as resolved?

Tags: drupal-7, flags

I am using the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module to mark particular Advanced Forum topics as resolved. I only want the main editor to be able to do this.

I have configured a flag so the editor can click on it to flag that node, but I can't work out how to just display "Resolved" to everyone else if the editor has set the flag on the node.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done so yet, I wonder have far you'd get if you would use a **global** flag for this, as explained in the community documentation within [Private flags vs global flags](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/flag). Here is a quote about it:

> Flags may be **per user**, meaning that each user has her own private "copy" of the flag; different users can flag, or unflag, a node individually. Or a flag may be **global**, meaning that any user who changes a flag changes it for everyone.

Comment: Thanks Pierre, I raised this question middle last year and I have resolved it.

Comment: OK, sorry for "answering" ... If you ever have some time for doing so, I'd be interested in reading about how you solved it (via an extra "answer" to this question) ...

Comment: Oh no don't take that the wrong way, I wasn't criticising. I'm sure your answer will be useful for someone else with the same issue. Thank you for answering.

Comment: Oeps, looks like I didn't use the correct phrasing in my prior comment (I'm not n8ive English ...), I just wanted to let you know I'm curious about "your" solution about it ... might be useful  for someone else "also", right?